# "Allocating an object of abstract class type" error although all functions have implementations

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I know questions about this error have been asked repeatedly, however none of the previous answers seem to solve my problem.

I have a pure abstract class `ITile`:

```
class ITile {
public:
    virtual ~ITile() {}
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual bool isWalkable() = 0;
    virtual bool isGoal() = 0;
};
```

And three subclasses that all implement these functions like so:

**Floor.h**

```
#include "ITile.h"

class Floor : public ITile {
public:
    Floor();
    virtual ~Floor();
    virtual void display() override;
    virtual bool isWalkable() override;
    virtual bool isGoal() override;
};
```

**Floor.cpp**

```
#include "Floor.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Floor::Floor() {}
Floor::~Floor() {}

void Floor::display() {
   cout << " ";
}

bool Floor::isWalkable() {
    return true;
}

bool Floor::isGoal() {
    return false;
}
```

When trying to compile the whole project I get the following output:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
In file included from ../src/main.cpp:1:
In file included from ../src/board.h:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:265:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:627:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1641:31: error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'ITile'
        ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
[...]
```

...followed by a bunch of notes. But the problem is, I guess, the error in the last line above.

So, what exactly are these `algorithm`, `memory` files and so on? How can I get rid of this error?

I'm using Eclipse Luna with the C/C++ plugin on Mac OS X (Mavericks) with the Developer Command Line Tools. Any more info gladly given upon request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You went a little too minimal in your example.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not so much that it's too minimal. It's that it's incomplete. He's missing the `main` function that ties everything together. The one that's almost certainly using a `vector<ITile>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver well, I myself hate reading through other people's complete projects. I thought this might be enough for a pro to find my mistake. What else should I post?

Comment: It looks like you are creating a `std::vector<ITile>`. You cannot do that since `ITile` is a abstract class.

Comment: @NicolBolas okay okay coming right up :D

Comment: @elisae__ We need to see how you are using it as that is where the error is coming from.

Comment: You're not supposed to post a "complete project". You're supposed to post a [MCVE]. And, to be blunt, if you haven't composed one yet, then you haven't finished your _own_ debugging before posting here. Also, when you post something that isn't an MCVE, the odds are very good that the question will be of no benefit to future visitors (because it's probably a question about _your code_, rather than about the programming language), which is a precondition for questions on this site.

Comment: @RSahu uuuhm yes, clearly it should be a `vector<ITile*>`. I suppose that solves the problem, but let me check.

Comment: @elisae__: Consider `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ITile>>`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Too slow, and in the wrong place.

Comment: All right all right guys, I'm taking this question down. I wasn't very patient, nor diligent. Sorry for bothering y'all.

Comment: You haven't flown into a fit of rage after being told all this, so as far as I'm concerned you're okay. Just remember for next time eh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "Too slow" yes! :) "Wrong place": not so sure about it, because we can still only speculate about the OP's code, so technically it's an off-topic question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I concede it's debateable as to whether it should be answered at this point, but if it is going to be answered then that should take place in the answer section.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a `std::vector<ITile>`, because `ITile`s cannot exist.

In order to make use of polymorphism in a container, you'll need to store pointers. Those pointers will point to dynamically-allocated objects of type `Floor`, `Wall`, `Ceiling`… whatever else you've got.

Consider a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ITile>>`.

Comment: I was just wondering if an empty `std::vector<ITile>` is fine (albeit useless) since C++11 as long as you don't invoke any operations which require a CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable type, seeing as how an abstract class is not an incomplete type.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Not sure how much the standard mandates about the implementation. If a vector were to preserve enough space for 5 `ITile`s, is that still okay? I realise it only _needs_ to know `sizeof(ITile)`, which it can do, and that in practice you're probably just going to get a block of `char`s to placement-new over when someone later creates some actual elements. But is that _guaranteed_? Hmm.

Comment: @ChristianHackl conforming implementation should allow this. Requirements to types stored in vector are mandated by functions called on said vector. And `vector::vector()` does not impose any requirements on underlying type.

Comment: @SergeyA: That's alright then. For simplicity's sake I shan't adjust the answer, but that's "good" to know.

Answer (score 2):

`ITile` is an abstract class.

For pre C++11 compilers, you cannot create a `std::vector<ITile>`. `std::vector` can be used only with types that are CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable. An abstract class is neither CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable.

If you are using a C++11, or later, compiler the type need not be CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable to construct a `std::vector`. Other member functions may impose those requirements. If your compiler is not strictly conformant, it will fail to construct a `std::vector` for such types.

More info:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable

Comment: And to add, RSahu, he will get there if @LightnessRacesinOrbit is lucky enough!

Comment: `std::vector` itself doesn't impose any requirements other than for the type to be `Erasble` (and complete before C++17). Requirements are only imposed by the `vector` members being called, and only if those members are actually called.